Peaks and gaps in log-return of XAUUSD 1-minute log-return density
I'm tinkering around a 1-minute XAUUSD data from March 2009-December 2023 to see if I can model it with a log-normal or log-t distribution and I happen to notice some interesting properties in the log-return ($log(\frac{close}{open})$). The zoomed-in density histogram below is the data log-return (blue) and the fitted t-distribution of the data:

and the one vs a fitted normal distribution:

I'm relatively new with financial data and I don't quite understand why these observations occur:

I noticed the log-return doesn't smoothly decay as it goes further from the peak, but instead have some smaller peaks of data. It's quite visible especially in the second plot where the blue distribution has periods where the density decays more slowly. I don't quite understand why this happen. Does this mean certain amount of price change is more likely than the others and price is more likely to move ins a certain step sizes? Will this affect the model and if so, how should I integrate this into the model?

I noticed a very large peak of low or no return (which I guess is to be expected for smaller timeframe data?) near the center of the distribution. About 99% of the log-return occur between log return of -0.001 and 0.001 (about 0.1% of price change) and 4% of the total data shows a 0 log-return (no-price change between open and close in 1 minute). I'm not really sure how to handle this data since it really mess up the distributions I'm trying to fit. Any model recommendations? Should I include the no-change in the data? Coming from a non-finance background, we usually treat these smaller movements as noises. While I cannot eliminate 99% of the data, is it alright to eliminate the even smaller price movements?

I also noticed the log-return of data nearer to 0 is more sparsely distributed from the bins in the histogram. Prices are concentrated in some bins while the adjacent bins are relatively lower. While it does make sense to me that price difference that are too small are less likely than a bigger one from minimum lot sizing and the chosen timeframe of 1 minute masks the smaller price movements, etc., shouldn't this just strictly mean lower frequency for lower price changes and not a more sparsely distributed data? Is this normal or an artifact of the computation or bad data or its because gold prices are less volatile in 2009 than 2023 or something else entirely?


Thank you in advance.

One explanation could be that some parts of the day are very illiquid, with not much trading, hence an over abundance of the zero bucket.  You could focus only on liquid periods

Another explanation is that pricing is discrete, not continuous. If the price is 2400.850 the next higher value is 2400.855 and the next lower value is 2400.845. Smaller changes are not allowed. Hnce the "spiky" look of the distribution of changes,
